# How to get the key value of child in firebase in Android using kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch the list of phone numbers who are opted for "plumber" job in this list also the numbers who has accepted the job or not in firebase using kotlin.

[image: This is the The Image for Reference of Data].

Comment: Can you add some code here that you have written so far?

Comment: What is the parent node of +91111111111? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: it itself is parent node

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking to [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) in a nested property, which you can do with:

```
// TODO: set ref to point to the parent node of your results
val query = ref.orderByChild("Plumber/accepted").equalTo(true)

query.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {
    override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildKey: String?) {
        println(snapshot.key) // "+91111111111"
    }
    ...
})
```

Comment: database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                var sb = StringBuilder()
                snapshot.children.forEach {
                    if (it.child("Garbage Picker").child("accepted").value.toString() == "false"){
                        sb.append(it.key + "\n")
                    }
                }
                textView.text = sb
            } override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })